# Installation error plugin WebSphere Application Server V7 in eclipse Mars

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, websphere-7

Because of cost saving necessities we are currently looking for a way to install the WAS7 developer tools in an eclipse Mars. We chose this version because of the dependency on JDK7. Currently we are still working with an IBM RAD 8.5 but want to switch the IDE.
Because of current server dependencies in the different software projects we need to use WAS7. We know the server version is out of support but any possible server migration is not within our responsibilities nor are we involved in any decision-making process at the moment and is therefore not an option.

We obtained "some help" from IBM, but their information has not been able to help us install WAS7 developer tools in the chosen eclipse.

We are able to reach a software site that allows us to select the WAS7 developer tools for installation, but when advancing in the plugin installation process we get a fatal error.

So we are asking if there is still a way to install WAS7 developer tools in an eclipse:

- An update site that works for WAS7 developer tools
- An eclipse version that allows for WAS7 developer tools installation
- A simple guide to help us install the plugin in the eclipse, in case a workaround needs to be applied

Any help is very much appreciated!

The information provided to us by IBM:

- https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/ibm-websphere-application-server-v85x-developer-tools
- https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/docs/websphere-developer-tools-releases/
- https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/downloads/#asset/tools-WebSphere_Developer_Tools_for_Eclipse_Mars
- https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/downloads/#asset/tools-IBM_Liberty_Developer_Tools_for_Eclipse_Neon
- https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/downloads/#asset/tools-IBM_WebSphere_Application_Server_V7.x__V8.0.x_Developer_Tools_for_Eclipse_Oxygen

All of these links lead to either an error or an incompatibility message (if you have prove of otherwise, please provide us details in the).

Our configuration:

- Update site: http://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/websphere/wasdev/V8.5/
- Eclipse version: Mars.2 Release (4.5.2)

The fatal error message in the installation process (my appologies for the wrap up):

> Software being installed: WebSphere® Application Server V7.0 Tools 8.5.1002.v20130402_2058 (com.ibm.websphere.wdt.st.v7.feature.group 8.5.1002.v20130402_2058)
>     Missing requirement: IBM Java EE UI Component 6.0.952.v20191201_1712 (com.ibm.etools.j2ee.ui 6.0.952.v20191201_1712) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.core [1.4.0,2.0.0)' but it could not be found
>     Missing requirement: Javaee Model 1.3.403.v20191201_1712 (com.ibm.etools.javaee.core 1.3.403.v20191201_1712) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.core [1.4.0,2.0.0)' but it could not be found
>     Missing requirement: Maven tools for Java EE - UI 1.0.0.v20121205_2240 (com.ibm.etools.maven.javaee.ui 1.0.0.v20121205_2240) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.core.runtime [3.6.0,3.9.0)' but it could not be found
>     Cannot satisfy dependency:
>       From: Maven Tools for Java EE 1.0.0.v20121205_2240 (com.ibm.etools.maven.javaee.feature.feature.group 1.0.0.v20121205_2240)
>       To: com.ibm.etools.maven.javaee.ui [1.0.0.v20121205_2240]
>     Cannot satisfy dependency:
>       From: Maven Tools for Java EE 1.2.0.v20191201_1712 (com.ibm.etools.maven.javaee.feature.feature.group 1.2.0.v20191201_1712)
>       To: com.ibm.etools.maven.javaee.ui [1.1.405.v20191201_1712]
>     Cannot satisfy dependency:
>       From: Maven tools for Java EE - UI 1.1.405.v20191201_1712 (com.ibm.etools.maven.javaee.ui 1.1.405.v20191201_1712)
>       To: bundle com.ibm.etools.javaee.core [1.1.0,2.0.0)
>     Cannot satisfy dependency:
>       From: IBM Bean Validation 1.0.4.v20191201_1712 (com.ibm.jee.bean.validation.feature.feature.group 1.0.4.v20191201_1712)
>       To: com.ibm.jee.bean.validation.ui [1.0.103.v20191201_1712]
>     Cannot satisfy dependency:
>       From: IBM Bean Validation UI Component 1.0.103.v20191201_1712 (com.ibm.jee.bean.validation.ui 1.0.103.v20191201_1712)
>       To: bundle com.ibm.etools.j2ee.ui [6.0.600,7.0.0)
>     Cannot satisfy dependency:
>       From: Java EE Development Tools 1.0.0.v20121205_0320 (com.ibm.wdt.javaee.feature.feature.group 1.0.0.v20121205_0320)
>       To: com.ibm.etools.maven.javaee.feature.feature.group 1.0.0
>     Cannot satisfy dependency:
>       From: Java EE Development Tools 1.0.400.v20191201_1712 (com.ibm.wdt.javaee.feature.feature.group 1.0.400.v20191201_1712)
>       To: com.ibm.jee.bean.validation.feature.feature.group 1.0.0
>     Cannot satisfy dependency:
>       From: WebSphere® Application Server V7.0 Tools 8.5.1002.v20130402_2058 (com.ibm.websphere.wdt.st.v7.feature.group 8.5.1002.v20130402_2058)
>       To: com.ibm.wdt.javaee.feature.feature.group 1.0.0

This is an image of the beginning of the installation process:
[image: start installation plugin]

This is an image of the error we receive (with part of the detailed message as mentioned above):
[image: end installation plugin]

Comment: The Java version required to run Java can be higher than the Java version used for your application, e.g. Eclipse 2019-09 requires Java 8 but can be used to write Java 7 (and even Java 1.3) code. Please show the issues you have when using Eclipse 2019-09 instead of Eclipse Mars. Please format error message as code snippets instead of quotes to preserve line breaks.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment! As far as I was investigating, Oxygen is the latest version in which the plugin for WAS V7.X is offered. When adding the update sites to a more recent version, like eclipse 2019-09, the option of installing WAS V7.X does not even appear between the available software options and therefore you cannot select it. Drag & drop options from the IBM website immediately generate a compatibility error.

Answer (score 1):

One 'core' error in the install log is:

```
requires 'bundle org.eclipse.core.runtime [3.6.0,3.9.0)'
```

This is saying that the org.eclipse.core.runtime plug-in is required with a version of at least 3.6.0 and **less than** 3.9.0. This restricts the possible versions of Eclipse to between Eclipse 3.6 and 3.8 (inclusive) or maybe Eclipse 4.2 (Juno). Nothing newer is going to meet this requirement.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer! I will give it an upvote because part of the errors disappeared, although it did not completely resolve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

After some additional exploring I got a perfect match between an eclipse and a plugin:

- [Download](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/mars/2/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers) eclipse Mars
- [Download](https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/downloads/#asset/tools-WebSphere_Developer_Tools_for_Eclipse_Mars) Developer tools for Mars from IBM tools site

As far as I tested, it was the only combination of the most recent eclipse IDE with a Developer tool that did not give any warning (installation in Oxygen generated an installation warning).

If anyone else experienced the same problem and resolved the issue with this answer, it can be accepted as the solution.